# What library to overlay text on a video?

Tags: video, text, overlay

I'd like to find a server side solution to overlay text on video, with following features:

- can define timing
- can define position
- can use a custom font
- basic text animation

I don't really mind the language, provided I can make it run on AWS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to implement my own solution involving :

- HTML canvas within a nodeJS server to display, animate text and images
- writing to disk each frame of my animation (ie. of my canvas) to a specific png
- merging all png into a transparent background video (qtrle codec) with FFMpeg
- overlaying the generated qtrle video with a background video still using FFMpeg

It's been tough but it's working quite reliably

Comment: have you considered creating an open source library for that task?

Answer (score 2):

FFMpeg might be your solution.  This will take your input file and display the text 'Fox Mulder' on the screen in red text with the tahoma font.  Between tells it to display starting at 10 seconds.  Acodec copy means copy the audio, vcodec libx264 says output h.264 in an mp4.  crf 25 is the lowest quality.  0 is the highest.

The manual will tell you about setting x and y for the text, calculating the values based on the input file, etc.

```
ffmpeg -benchmark -hide_banner  -y -i INPUT_FILE.mp4 -vf "drawtext=enable='between(t,10,35)':fontfile=/PATH/TO/tahoma.ttf:fontcolor='Red':fontsize=24:text='Fox Mulder':x=(w-tw)/2:y=(h/PHI)+th,  -acodec copy -vcodec libx264  -crf 25 OUTPUT_FILE.mp4
```